# django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet. when I run uwsgi

Tags: python, uwsgi

In my virtual environment, when I use `uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini` to run the uWSGI.

I get the bellow error:

```
mapped 543168 bytes (530 KB) for 20 cores
*** Operational MODE: threaded ***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Qiyun02/wsgi.py", line 18, in <module>
    from 管理员后台.网站管理.admin_website_chat.views import sio
  File "./管理员后台/网站管理/admin_website_chat/views.py", line 2, in <module>
    from 管理员后台.用户管理admin_usermanage.models import User
  File "./管理员后台/用户管理/admin_usermanage/models.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
  File "/home/lll/repo/myProject/venv_dist/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/home/lll/repo/QmyProjectyun02/venv_dist/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 52, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/home/lll/repo/myProject/venv_dist/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 110, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
File "/home/lll/repo/myProject/venv_dist/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 247, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/home/lll/repo/myProject/venv_dist/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 125, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 32347)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 32349, cores: 20)
spawned uWSGI http 1 (pid: 32350)
```

But in my virtual environment I use the python check, there is no issues.

```
(venv_dist) [ldl@www myProject]$ python3 manage.py check 
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
```

I also can `python3 manage.py runserver` in my virtual environment.

Why there get this `AppRegistryNotReady` error when I run uwsgi?

---

Or, does the uwsgi support non-latin characters? I have some Chinese characters there.

Answer (score 0):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Qiyun02/wsgi.py", line 18, in <module>
    from 管理员后台.网站管理.admin_website_chat.views import sio
  ...
```

you should not import things from your `view` in `uwsgi.py`, because `django` has not setup when `uwsgi.py` is loaded.

---

and when you run `python3 manage.py runserver`, it has nothing to do with `uwsgi.py`.

Answer (score 0):

Because when use the the django has not setup, you should setup it before your code:

```
import django 

django.setup() 
... # your code
```

Hope this help you.